# glsl -= mad optimization

Tags: opengl, glsl

Question about GLSL MAD ("multiply and add") optimization.

According to this http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Optimizations we should help GLSL compiler to optimize mad expressions. It's all clear form me with

```
result += x*y
```

It should looks like:

```
result = x*y + result
```

---

But what to do with -= ?

```
result -= x*y
```

If I wrote:

```
result = result - x*y
```

This will not be "multiply and add" 
And if:

```
result = -x*y + result
```

Does it optimize it? I worry because of **-x**

Just want to clarify this thing to myself.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really hard to guess what a particular compiler/optimizer will do in any specific situation. With GLSL, you have the situation that there are lots of different implementations (and versions of them) out in the wild.

In general, I would expect that `result += x*y` would never lead to another optimization result than `result = result + x*y` - it is just syntactic sugar after all and not some different operation.

If you want to see what some compiler does for your code, I recommend you to have a look at [AMD's shader analyzer](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/gpu-shaderanalyzer/) which will show you the compiler results. Also, you can use [nvidia's command line compiler](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/cgc.html) from their [CG toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cg-toolkit), which also compiles GLSL. It will only output ARB assembly level vertex/fragment programs and not shouw you real instruction level code, but it will still allow you to see where the optimizer made a MAD out of your GLSL construct.

Comment: Does AMD's shader analyzer works for nVidia cards? Does cg toolkit has some gui? And still.... what about -= ? :))

Comment: @tower120: AMDs shader analyzer works completely independent of the GPU: it just compiles the code and does static performance analysis. NVIDIAs CG compiler also works on the CPU. For the cases I suggested to use it here, the GPU doesn't really matter. I don't know of any GUI for it - it is a compiler after all.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add another resource:
http://www.humus.name/Articles/Persson_LowLevelThinking.pdf
is a good run-down of ways you can steer the compiler towards more optimal code.

The advice is not glsl-specific, but I thought of it when I saw your question because he does stress that you should write code which has a good chance of boiling down to MAD instuctions.